# Force date as new line on reading non-delimited text file

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am trying to read in and work with a horribly formatted debug log. There are no consistent delimeters and it does not appear line breaks are encoded either.

What I'd like to do is read in and parse the data to have a new line for each date (YYYY-MM-DD format).

I am trying to work within the `tidyverse` but cannot seem to get something that will parse the file correctly.

Is there a way to force lines to be delimited by a date pattern?

None of these work:

```
library(tidyverse)
Log_File <- read.table("Example.txt", header = F, fill = T, skip = 1, allowEscapes = TRUE)
Log_File <- read_delim("Example.txt", col_names = F, delim = " ", n_max = 2)
Log_File <- read_lines("Example.txt", skip = 1, n_max = -1L, na = character(),
                       locale = default_locale(), progress = interactive())




> Log_File
                                           V1                                    V2                               V3       V4       V5                                                                         V6            V7
1                                  2019-09-20                          14:06:18.952                          [Error]   [main]        > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:):         Error
2                                  2019-09-20                          14:06:18.953                          [Error]   [main]        >                        AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName():        Unable
3                                       error                                     :                                {                                                                                                           
4                                        code                                     :                             404,                                                                                                           
5                                     message                                     : Not Found.  Could not get object        ,                                                                                                  
6                                      status                                     :                       GET_OBJECT                                                                                                           
7                                           }                                                                                                                                                                                  
8                                          }, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com,                   data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a                                                                   207b0a20      20202022
9                                    74206765                              74206f62                         6a656374 222c0a20 20202022                                                                   73746174      7573223a
10 ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus,                ResponseErrorCode=404}                                                                                                                                            
11                                 2019-09-20                          14:06:18.953                          [Error]   [main]        >                        AlertService.swift[line:314]-retrieveProfileName(): AlertSettings
12                                      error                                     :                                {                                                                                                           
13                                       code                                     :                             404,                                                                                                           
14                                    message                                     : Not Found.  Could not get object        ,                                                                                                  
15                                     status                                     :                       GET_OBJECT                                                                                                           
16                                          }                                                                                                                                                                                  
17                                         }, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com,                   data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a                                                                   207b0a20      20202022
18                                   74206765                              74206f62                         6a656374 222c0a20 20202022                                                                   73746174      7573223a
19 ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus,                ResponseErrorCode=404}                                                                                                                                            
20                                 2019-09-20                          14:06:18.957                          [Error]   [main]        > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:):         Error
```

I know linking to a text file is frowned upon, so here is some raw text, hopefully this works:

```
2019-09-20 14:06:18.952 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:): Error occurs when download filestorage data with description: Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.
2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName(): Unable to get AlertSettings Name: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist." UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 642e2020 436f756c 64206e6f 74206765 74206f62 6a656374 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20224745 545f4f42 4a454354 220a2020 7d0a7d>, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:314]-retrieveProfileName(): AlertSettings Name object missing: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist." UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 642e2020 436f756c 64206e6f 74206765 74206f62 6a656374 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20224745 545f4f42 4a454354 220a2020 7d0a7d>, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
2019-09-20 14:06:18.957 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:): Error occurs when download filestorage data with description: Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.
```

Here is a dput as read in with:

```
Log_File <- read_delim("Example.txt", col_names = F, delim = " ")


Data <- structure(list(X1 = c("2019-09-20", "2019-09-20", "error\": {\n    \"code\": 404,\n    \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not get object\",\n    \"status\": \"GET_OBJECT", 
"  }", "},", "2019-09-20", "error\": {\n    \"code\": 404,\n    \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not get object\",\n    \"status\": \"GET_OBJECT", 
"  }", "},", "2019-09-20"), X2 = c("14:06:18.952", "14:06:18.953", 
NA, NA, "bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com,", "14:06:18.953", 
NA, NA, "bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com,", "14:06:18.957"
), X3 = c("[Error]", "[Error]", NA, NA, "data=<7b0a2020", "[Error]", 
NA, NA, "data=<7b0a2020", "[Error]"), X4 = c("[main]", "[main]", 
NA, NA, "22657272", "[main]", NA, NA, "22657272", "[main]"), 
    X5 = c(">", ">", NA, NA, "6f72223a", ">", NA, NA, "6f72223a", 
    ">"), X6 = c("CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:):", 
    "AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName():", NA, 
    NA, "207b0a20", "AlertService.swift[line:314]-retrieveProfileName():", 
    NA, NA, "207b0a20", "CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:):"
    ), X7 = c("Error", "Unable", NA, NA, "20202022", "AlertSettings", 
    NA, NA, "20202022", "Error"), X8 = c("occurs", "to", NA, 
    NA, "636f6465", "Name", NA, NA, "636f6465", "occurs"), X9 = c("when", 
    "get", NA, NA, "223a2034", "object", NA, NA, "223a2034", 
    "when"), X10 = c("download", "AlertSettings", NA, NA, "30342c0a", 
    "missing:", NA, NA, "30342c0a", "download"), X11 = c("filestorage", 
    "Name:", NA, NA, "20202020", "Error", NA, NA, "20202020", 
    "filestorage"), X12 = c("data", "Error", NA, NA, "226d6573", 
    "Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain", NA, NA, "226d6573", "data"
    ), X13 = c("with", "Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain", NA, NA, 
    "73616765", "Code=-13010", NA, NA, "73616765", "with"), X14 = c("description:", 
    "Code=-13010", NA, NA, "223a2022", "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.", 
    NA, NA, "223a2022", "description:"), X15 = c("Object", "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.", 
    NA, NA, "4e6f7420", "UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data,", 
    NA, NA, "4e6f7420", "Object"), X16 = c("App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data", 
    "UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data,", 
    NA, NA, "466f756e", "ResponseBody={", NA, NA, "466f756e", 
    "App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data"
    ), X17 = c("does", "ResponseBody={", NA, NA, "642e2020", 
    NA, NA, NA, "642e2020", "does"), X18 = c("not", NA, NA, NA, 
    "436f756c", NA, NA, NA, "436f756c", "not"), X19 = c("exist.", 
    NA, NA, NA, "64206e6f", NA, NA, NA, "64206e6f", "exist.")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L
    ), col = c("X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", 
    "X1", "X1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", 
    "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", NA, NA, NA, NA), expected = c("delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "19 columns", "19 columns", "19 columns", "19 columns", "delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", "delimiter or quote", 
    "19 columns", "19 columns", "19 columns", "19 columns"), 
    actual = c(":", "c", ":", "m", ":", "N", ",", "s", ":", "G", 
    "17 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "40 columns", ":", 
    "c", ":", "m", ":", "N", ",", "s", ":", "G", "16 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "40 columns"), file = c("'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", 
    "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'", "'Example.txt'")), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X13 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X14 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X15 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X17 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X19 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 0), class = "col_spec"))
```

Any suggestions for appending rows without dates to the previous row/line?

Comment: It might help more to see the first few lines of the file in its raw state instead of post-read.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question with some raw text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use a delimiter to do that, but a simple pattern match (line starts with `20`) should suffice:

Sample data, where you should use the `readLines` command to read all text in, I'm faking it here:

```r
# loglines <- readLines(filename)
loglines <- strsplit('2019-09-20 14:06:18.952 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:): Error occurs when download filestorage data with description: Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.
2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName(): Unable to get AlertSettings Name: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist." UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 642e2020 436f756c 64206e6f 74206765 74206f62 6a656374 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20224745 545f4f42 4a454354 220a2020 7d0a7d>, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:314]-retrieveProfileName(): AlertSettings Name object missing: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist." UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 642e2020 436f756c 64206e6f 74206765 74206f62 6a656374 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20224745 545f4f42 4a454354 220a2020 7d0a7d>, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
2019-09-20 14:06:18.957 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:): Error occurs when download filestorage data with description: Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.', "\n")[[1]]
```

Using this example, we group the lines together with `grepl` (returns a vector of `logical`s), and `cumsum` on that:

```r
grepl("^20", loglines)
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
cumsum(grepl("^20", loglines))
#  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

So the first line is by itself, the next 7 are together, etc.

```r
combined <- as.list(by(loglines, cumsum(grepl("^20", loglines)), paste, collapse = "\n"))
str(combined)
# List of 4
#  $ 1: chr "2019-09-20 14:06:18.952 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:valu"| __truncated__
#  $ 2: chr "2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName(): Unable to get Aler"| __truncated__
#  $ 3: chr "2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:314]-retrieveProfileName(): AlertSettings Name"| __truncated__
#  $ 4: chr "2019-09-20 14:06:18.957 [Error] [main] > CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:valu"| __truncated__

# perhaps for convenience:
combined <- unlist(as.list(combined), use.names = FALSE)

# one element:
combined[[2]]
# [1] "2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 [Error] [main] > AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName(): Unable to get AlertSettings Name: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 \"Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist.\" UserInfo={object=App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data, ResponseBody={\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 404,\n    \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not get object\",\n    \"status\": \"GET_OBJECT\"\n  }\n}, bucket=integration-c5068.appspot.com, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 642e2020 436f756c 64206e6f 74206765 74206f62 6a656374 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20224745 545f4f42 4a454354 220a2020 7d0a7d>, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object App/Data/Users/U0bGtkevMkc8Z94KFIoYSKy87sS2/Modes/RealMode/Alert/Data does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}"
```

(Note the embedded newlines within each string. This can easily be changed by changing `collapse=`.)

This example might be parsed with `read.fwf`, such as

```r
out <- read.fwf(textConnection(combined), widths=c(24, 8, 7, 999), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 16 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "2019-09-20 14:06:18.952 " "2019-09-20 14:06:18.953 " "  \"error\": {" "    \"code\": 404," ...
#  $ V2: chr  "[Error] " "[Error] " NA NA ...
#  $ V3: chr  "[main] " "[main] " NA NA ...
#  $ V4: chr  "> CloudStorageExtension.swift[line:38]-downloadData(node:storageObj:value:): Error occurs when download filesto"| __truncated__ "> AlertService.swift[line:310]-retrieveProfileName(): Unable to get AlertSettings Name: Error Domain=FIRStorage"| __truncated__ NA NA ...
```

This might benefit from removing surrounding whitespace, such as with

```r
out <- lapply(out, trimws)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!! Your explanations are great!